# Ubuntu Python os.path.join error reading file

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04

On Windows, this works fine, however, when I try to read the file in Ubuntu, I get the error, "no such file or directory." Everything was kept the same.

```
import os
def load_ablist(shopID):
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    path = os.path.join(cwd, "ABlists/%i.txt" % shopID)
    f = open(path, mode='r')
    ablist = (f.read()).split(sep="\n")
    f.close()
    return ablist
```

Comment: GNU/Linux is case sensitive system. ABlist might be the problem? Also, traceback log with line number would help.

Comment: Thanks for the help! You were right, it was ABList, instead of ABlist. On windows, it worked fine so I didn't catch the mistake till I looked it over after reading your comment.

Answer (score 2):

When I try to run your code, it tells me this error.

```
path = os.path.join(cwd, "ABlists/%i.txt" % (shopID))
TypeError: %i format: a number is required, not str



import os

def load_ablist(shopID)
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    path = os.path.join(cwd, "ABlists/%s.txt" % str(shopID))
    f = open(path, mode='r')
    ablist = (f.read()).split(sep="\n")
    f.close()
    return ablist

load_ablist(123)
```

this works for me.

```
path = os.path.join(cwd, "ABlists/%s.txt" % str(shopID))
```

Can you try with this?

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time! Unfortunately, it was a capitalization error which I didn't catch. Really appreciate your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. What's more important is you got your problem solved and you know it.